# Fade out page load next page using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

As noted in the title I'm trying to figure out how to fade out my current page and load the next page. I've managed to do this but the fadeout does not complete before the new page link fires. How would I change my code to complete the fadeout prior to going to the next page? Thanks for any help!

```
$( "#droppable" ).droppable({
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $('#target').hide()
         $('#target2').hide()
         $('#target2').hide()
         $('#black').fadeIn()
         $(location).attr('href', '/dreamjob').delay(1200)
      }
    });
```

FYI: The #black is  fullscreen black css.

Comment: Set the fadeIn to last 1200 too?

Comment: I've tired and it doesn't seem to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably just do a jQuery `.fadeOut()` on the container of the `#target` elements and then go to the next page in the callback of the `fadeOut` call.

Something like this:

```
$('#target-container').fadeOut('slow', function() {
  $(location).attr('href', '/dreamjob') 
});
```

You can find the documentation for the jQuery `fadeOut` method [here](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/).

Or, if you're fading out the entire page, just replace the `#target-container` with the `body` of the page.